# how to make more links?

Tags: jquery, button, html, hyperlink

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {            
        var linkas = $("#button").attr("value");
         $('#button').click(function(){
            $.get(linkas, function(data){
                $('#out').html(data);
            });           
        });
    });  
</script> 

<a id="button" href="#" value="test2.php" >LINKAS</a>
<div id="out"></div>';
```

First link forks fine, but if I add another link with different value it doesn't work.
How to add more similar links ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's very unclear. You also do understand that value technically isn't an attribute of an anchor tag and that if you are scrolled down in your page, when they click your link, it is going to shift them all the way to the top. Try `href="javascript:void(0)"` for better results.

Comment: t.y. for advice.
I want to make more links in page but works only first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {            
    $('.ajax').click(function(){
        $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data){
            $('#out').html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

.
.

```
<a class="ajax" href="test2.php" >LINKAS</a>
<a class="ajax" href="test3.php" >LINKAS</a>
<div id="out"></div>
```

like: http://jsfiddle.net/Jacek_FH/hzudP/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('#out').html(data);
```

Try

```
$('#out').append(data);
```

EDIT:

I changed your script to get the currently clicked button instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {            
      $('#button').click(function(){
        var linkas = $(this).attr("value");
        $.get(linkas, function(data){
            $('#out').html(data);
        });           
    });
  });  
</script>
```

Comment: I want to add more links
<a id="button" href="#" value="test1.php" >LINKAS</a>
<a id="button" href="#" value="test2.php" >LINKAS</a>
but other links just dont't work.

Comment: Edited my answer, this line `var linkas = $("#button").attr("value");` will not consider the link you just clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function instead of an invalid attribute.

Function:

```
function makeLink(linkas) {
    $.get(linkas, function(data){
        $('#out').html(data);
    });
}
```

HTML :

```
<a id="button" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="makeLink('test2.php')">LINKAS</a>
<div id="out"></div>
```